# parsing multi row Excel spreadsheet into maxscript

Tags: excel, 3dsmax, maxscript

Im trying to make a multidimensional array from excel data. I have row 1, representing cone 1, with 5 columns of values. I largely am unsure what the best way to save my data would be, I think.

My first thought was to parse the data as a CSV using python csv module but that doesnt seem to easily represent the multirow aspect, although Im sure I will eventually figure out how to write the parsing for it.

only used Unity c# so kinda tough without good docs, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Might be best to create a struct with the columns that you need and an array that will hold all the rows. Loop through the csv file with simple Max Script readLine command and filterString with "," this will get you an array that you can populate an instance of the struct with and add the struct instance to the array. You could also just use nested arrays if you like.